# export without dbms_fga

Tags: oracle, oracle9i

I use DBMS_FGA.ADD_POLICY, e.g. I have policies for some tables. Now I have to export data from these tables to another database with exp/imp of oracle. During transfer data policies are transferred too. How do I transfer data without transferring policies? I use oracle 9.2

Answer (score 0):

you should grant the user that does the expot the system pliviledge exempt access policy that should do the trick